# Foreign Key in user defined table type

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I have a user defined tabletype

```sql
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[et] AS TABLE(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [scId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [eN] [int] NOT NULL,
    [suppId] [int] NOT NULL,
)
GO
```

Than the target table I am trying to update/insert in to target table which is

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [scId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [eN] [int] NOT NULL,
    [suppId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[t_test]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_test__supplyr] FOREIGN KEY([suppId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[supplyr] ([id])
GO
```

When I pass the table from my code using

```cs
  SqlParameter param=  cmdd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@mt", dt3));
```

I get error.
   The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint........ 
 Problem is Target table has the foreign key constrains while the user define table doesnt. How can I fix this problem? Thanks

Store procedure doing merge is

```sql
ALTER procedure [dbo].[testing2]
@mt[dbo].[et] readonly 
 as 
Begin
merge into [dbo].[test] as Target
using @mt as Source 
on Target.suppId =Source.suppId
when matched then 
update set target.eN=Source.eN
when not matched then 
insert (sCId,eN,suppId)
values (Source.sCId, Source.eN, Source.suppId);
End
```

Comment: You're not showing us the `merge` statement where the issue arises. And the fix will almost certainly not involve adding a FK constraint to the table type, but will involve making sure that the correct data is in `dt3`. So, please add the `merge` statement, and please show how `dt3` gets populated.

Comment: Updated the stored procedure code showing merge statment

Comment: If you edit your question again, please try to make sure that your narrative *isn't* indented by four spaces, but that your code is. Also, because you've got two languages involved, I'm having to put `<-- language` markers above each code sample to make the syntax highlighting work correctly for each language. When editing, it helps to check the preview before saving changes (you usually have to click outside the edit box to check the syntax highlighting is working, in my experience)